# TP-Link WN822n v3 (RTL8192cu) on Kubuntu 15.04 Beta 2 (linux 3.19.0-10-generic)

Tags: networking, wireless, dkms, 15.04

i've just installed Kubuntu 15.04 Beta 2 and i'm looking for a way to get the wifi adapter to work. The old ways of installing the driver using dkms don't seem to work anymore because of the newer kernel. Do you guys know how i can get my internet to work?
The standard driver lists all available networks, but I'm not able to connect to any of them.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How does it "[not] work anymore" because of the newer kernel? Please elaborate.

Comment: I cannot connect with the internet.

Comment: I tried to install it using dkms, but failed because of the wrong kernel when executing sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.9

Comment: What exactly does it show when you try to install it?

Comment: pastebins: console output - http://pastebin.com/9WdYTPrC

Comment: make.log - http://pastebin.com/BAh135VU

Comment: It appears to have failed because you do not have gcc installed. Run `sudo apt-get install build-essential` and try again.

Comment: I don't have internet on that pc :( That's the reason i'm trying to install my wifi stick

Comment: [This question on Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline) might help with your problem.

Comment: Thanks but maybe it will work now without doing that - I downloaded all packages and requirement manually ^^

Comment: Works after install gcc - Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `make.log` you added in a comment shows that the dkms build is failing because `gcc` is missing. You can install either `gcc` or `build-essential` with `sudo apt-get install gcc` or `sudo apt-get install build-essential`.